# Calling Fortran DLL in Matlab with the help of C++

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, fortran, silverfrost-fortran

I have a fortran code and want to run it in MATLAB (2019). I want to stick with silverfrost (64-bit) compiler (FTN95) to compile my initial fortran code.
In order to find out how it works, I started with a simple code in Fortran: (multiply.f90)

```
double precision function Mul(nummer1, nummer2)
implicit none
double precision :: nummer1, nummer2
Mul = nummer1 * nummer2
end
```

I compiled it as a dll data and used this dll in C++ to generate a C++ dll (64-bit) to use it in MATLAB. The C++ dll is generated in Visual Studio 2015. Here is my C++ code (Cppdll.cpp):

```
// Cppdll.cpp
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Cppdll.h"

using namespace std;

typedef double(*FUNCPOINTER)(double &var1, double &var2);

    double DLLRes(double num1, double num2)
    {
        HINSTANCE hDLL;
        FUNCPOINTER myFuncPointer;
        double result = -999.99;

        hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"multiply.dll");

        if (hDLL != NULL)
        {
            myFuncPointer = (FUNCPOINTER)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "MUL");
            if (!myFuncPointer)
            {
                result = -999.999;
            }
            else
            {
                result = myFuncPointer(num1, num2);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and the corresponding header (Cppdll.h):

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) double DLLRes(double num1, double num2);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I put these dlls (multiply.dll and Cppdll.dll) in MATLAB path, and load the Cppdll in the program. By loading the dll, MATLAB  does not complain, but as I call the dll function (e.g. `calllib('Cppdll','DLLRes',2.1,5.23)`), MATLAB crashes unexpectedly, i.e. it usually works at the beginning and the results are correct but after a while MATLAB crashes with/without an error message. The error messages (if shown) are different but they all complain about Silverfrost exception handler:

[Error sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKKJP.png)

[Error sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfTKv.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ2GQ.png)

I should also mention MATLAB gives me the following warning as I run `[notfound,warnings] = loadlibrary('Cppdll.dll','Cppdll.h')` command:

```
warnings =

    'Cppdll.h
     Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated here (and will be fatal in Perl 5.30), passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/struct([^;,{(]*){ <-- HERE (.*?)\}([^;])*;/ at C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\general\private\prototypes.pl line 912.
     Cppdll_thunk_pcwin64.c
        Bibliothek "Cppdll_thunk_pcwin64.lib" und Objekt "Cppdll_thunk_pcwin64.exp" werden erstellt.
     '
```

Where did I make a mistake and how this problem can be solved?

Thx in advance!

Comment: Why not write a Fortran MEX-file? This seems overly complex...

Comment: @CrisLuengo    In MATLAB website, it is mentioned in order to write a Fortran MEX-file a supported Fortran compiler is required and Silverfrost compiler (FTN95) is not in this list.

Comment: The other option to simplify your code is to statically link the Fortran code to the C++ interface.

Comment: fortran95 is too old, you'd better wrap you fortan95 code as an exe which reads input by file and writes output by another file. If you want it to be faster, you can make this exe a service,  which exchage data with matlab by memory or pipe or RPC.